# Calculate total attendance for each workshop

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

[image: DB Tables]

I want to get overall attendance in each workshop. NumberOFWeeks column holds the number of weeks the workshop runs. for example Workshop 101 runs for 6 weeks meaning 6 days.

So far I have done this which gives me the total number of entries but how can I only include results for selective days. For example only count attendance on 01/04/2015, 02/04/2015, 05/04/2015 only

> `SELECT
>   COUNT(attendance.AttendanceID) as 'Total Attendance'
>   FROM
>   student
>   INNER JOIN attendance ON attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID
>   WHERE
>   student.WorkshopID = '101'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would give you the total across all three of those days:

```
SELECT COUNT(attendance.AttendanceID) as 'Total Attendance'
FROM student
INNER JOIN attendance ON attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID
  AND attendance.Date IN ('01/04/2015', '02/04/2015', '05/04/2015')
WHERE student.WorkshopID = '101'
```

If you wanted the total separately for each of those dates, use this:

```
SELECT attendance.Date, COUNT(attendance.AttendanceID) as 'Total Attendance'
FROM student
INNER JOIN attendance ON attendance.StudentID = student.StudentID
  AND attendance.Date IN ('01/04/2015', '02/04/2015', '05/04/2015')
WHERE student.WorkshopID = '101'
GROUP BY attendance.Date
```

Try this for overall attendance. Keep in mind I didn't have time to setup the schema, so this is untested:

```
SELECT wsdata.WorkshopID
  , wsdata.TotalAttendanceDaysPossible
  , adata.TotalAttendanceDaysActual
  , ((adata.TotalAttendanceDaysActual / wsdata.TotalAttendanceDaysPossible) * 100) AS OverallAttendance
FROM (
  SELECT ws1.WorkshopID
    , ws1.NumberOfWeeks AS TotalDays
    , COUNT(s1.StudentID) AS TotalStudents
    , ws1.NumberOfWeeks * COUNT(s1.StudentID) AS TotalAttendanceDaysPossible
  FROM workshop ws1
  INNER JOIN student s1 on ws1.WorkshopID = s1.WorkshopID
  GROUP BY ws1.WorkshopID
    , ws1.NumberOfWeeks
) wsdata
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT s2.WorkshopID
    , COUNT(a.AttendanceID) AS TotalAttendanceDaysActual
  FROM attendance a
  INNER JOIN student s2 ON a.StudentID = s2.StudentID
  GROUP BY s2.WorkshopID
) adata ON wsdata.WorkshopID = adata.WorkshopID
WHERE wsdata.WorkshopID = '101'
```

Comment: Thank you so much the queries work perfectly. To get the overall percentage I need to do total students X total workshop days = Total possible attendance . then total actual attendance / Total possible attendance * 100 should give me the correct percentage I think

Comment: See my latest edit, added an attempt at the overall attendance. Should at least get you going if it is not already correct.